# Attaching Visual leak detector to a process running as windows service

Tags: visual-c++, service, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, visual-leak-detector

How to use [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) to attach to a process running as a windows service.
If someone has used this tool to detect memory leaks for service, please let me know the procedure.

I am including "vld.h" in my source file as in the documentation nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Compile your service in debug with vld.h included.
2. Start your service from the Services Control Manager (no debugger involved yet)
3. Start Visual Studio - in the Debug Menu select attach to process
4. Select your process (your service) - make sure to enable native debugging
5. Stop your service with the debugger still attached and you should get output in the debug window.

Comment: Unfortunately i m not getting VLD Output in debug window after stopping the service. The Output window shows its usual output: The program 'xyz.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: What u have written i m supposed to accept your answer as i solved it by including vld.h at a different place.